# How can I get my Heroku variables in my react folder?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, environment-variables, mern, dotenv

I have a react application using the MERN (mongo, express, react, node) stack on heroku.
I have some environment variables stored in Heroku that get read into the root of my project. However the actual react application is nested within a folder of the project. Here is the file structure

```
.
├── client (react app)
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   └── src
├── controllers
├── routes
├── models
├── server.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
└── .env
```

My environment variables are named REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN, and REACT_APP_MONGODB_URI. These environment variables are available in the server.js file at the root of the project. However they are not available in the client folder (my react app). How can I set this up so the environment variables from Heroku flow through the entire project?
FYI if I add a .env file within the client folder I can access those variables. It seems like react is unable to access environment variables outside the actual react application.

Here is what I have in the package.json at the project root: [image: package.json]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your react app would need to be built prior to deploy (unless you have some kind of CI going). So you'd build it using your local `.env` then deploy to whatever host you wanted.

Comment: If you are doing SSR stuff then that would be a NodeJS server that can read from process.env

Comment: IM having issues with this today. Any updates?